# Code runs after catch statement catches and error and returns in react native firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am having issue whenever I catch an error and return from a function, by code after the catch block still runs. Here is my two functions that I use:

```
    usernameTaken: async (username) => {
        const user = await firebase.firestore().collection("uniqueUsers").doc(username).get();
        if (user.exists) {
            alert("Username is taken. Try again with another username.");
            throw new Error('Username is taken. Try again with another username.');
        }
    },
    changeUsername: async (currentUsername, newUsername) => {
      try {
          var user = Firebase.getCurrentUser();
          Firebase.usernameTaken(newUsername);
      } catch (err) {
          alert(err.message);
          return;
      }
      await db.collection('uniqueUsers').doc(currentUsername).delete();
      await db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update({username: newUsername});
      await db.collection("uniqueUsers").doc(newUsername).set({username: newUsername});
      alert("Congratulations! You have successfully updated your username.");
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate any help for this problem, as I have been struggling with it for over 2 days now and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: If that suits your usecase you can put last 4 lines in try block so they will only run in case there is no exception.
In case of any conditional exception you can simply throw an error in try block

Comment: I tried to place the last 4 lines in the try block after the username taken part, but it still does not work

Comment: can you plz explain what error you get.

Try this check if your values are empty or not defined throw some error.

e.g.  
          cosnt user = Firebase.getCurrentUser();
          const name = Firebase.usernameTaken(newUsername);
          
          // throwing error
           if(name == "")  throw "is empty";
          
      await db.collection('uniqueUsers').doc(currentUsername).delete();

Comment: where you exactly wanna stop execution and on which condition. So, I can update code accordingly

Comment: Wait actually your error checking method fixed my issue. If you put the solution as a comment I can mark it as the answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: you are welcome :) plz accept my answer. Happy coding !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code, the `usernameTaken()` promise is floating, because you didn't use `await`. Because it was floating, your `catch()` handler will never catch it's error.

```
changeUsername: async (currentUsername, newUsername) => {
  try {
      const user = Firebase.getCurrentUser();
      /* here -> */ await Firebase.usernameTaken(newUsername);
  } catch (err) {
      alert(err.message);
      return;
  }
  /* ... other stuff ... */
}
```

---

### Additional Points

#### `usernameTaken` should return a boolean

You should change `usernameTaken` to return a boolean. This is arguably better rather than using `alert()` (which blocks execution of your code) or throwing an error.

```
usernameTaken: async (username) => {
  const usernameDoc = await firebase.firestore().collection("uniqueUsers").doc(username).get();
  return usernameDoc.exists; // return a boolean whether the doc exists
}
```

#### Securely claim and release usernames

Based on your current code, you have no protections for someone coming along and just deleting any usernames in your database or claiming a username that was taken between the time you last checked it's availability and when you call `set()` for the new username. You should secure your database so that a user can only write to a username they own.

Add the owner's ID to the document:

```
"/uniqueUsers/{username}": {
  username: "username",
  uid: "someUserId"
}
```

This then allows you to lock edits/deletions to the user who owns that username.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /uniqueUsers/{username} {
      // new docs must have { username: username, uid: currentUser.uid }
      allow create: if request.auth != null
                    && request.resource.data.username == username
                    && request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
                    && request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["uid", "username"]);

      // any logged in user can get this doc
      allow read: if request.auth != null;

      // only the linked user can delete this doc
      allow delete: if request.auth != null
                    && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;

      // only the linked user can edit this doc, as long as username and uid are the same
      allow update: if request.auth != null
                    && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
                    && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).unchangedKeys().hasAll(["uid", "username"]) // make sure username and uid are unchanged
                    && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).changedKeys().size() == 0; // make sure no other data is added
    }
  }
}
```

#### Atomically update your database

You are modifying your database in a way that could corrupt it. You could delete the old username, then fail to update your current username which would mean that you never link your new username. To fix this, you should use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to apply all these changes together. If any one were to fail, nothing is changed.

```
await db.collection("uniqueUsers").doc(currentUsername).delete();
await db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update({username: newUsername});
await db.collection("uniqueUsers").doc(newUsername).set({username: newUsername});
```

becomes

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const batch = db.batch();

batch.delete(db.collection("uniqueUsers").doc(currentUsername));
batch.update(db.collection("users").doc(user.uid), { username: newUsername });
batch.set(db.collection("uniqueUsers").doc(newUsername), { username: newUsername });

await batch.commit();
```

#### Usernames should be case-insensitive

Your current usernames are case-sensitive which is not recommended if you expect your users to type/write out their profile's URL. Consider how `"example.com/MYUSERNAME"`, `"example.com/myUsername"` and `"example.com/myusername"` would all be different users. If someone scribbled out their username on a piece of paper, you'd want all of those to go to the same user's profile.

```
usernameTaken: async (username) => {
  const usernameDoc = await firebase.firestore().collection("uniqueUsers").doc(username.toLowerCase()).get();
  return usernameDoc.exists; // return a boolean whether the doc exists
},
changeUsername: async (currentUsername, newUsername) => {
  const lowerCurrentUsername = currentUsername.toLowerCase();
  const lowerNewUsername = newUsername.toLowerCase();

  /* ... */

  return lowerNewUsername; // return the new username to show success
}
```

#### The result

Combining this all together, gives:

```
usernameTaken: async (username) => {
  const usernameDoc = await firebase.firestore().collection("uniqueUsers").doc(username).get();
  return usernameDoc.exists; // return a boolean
},
changeUsername: async (currentUsername, newUsername) => {
  const user = Firebase.getCurrentUser();
  if (user === null) {
    throw new Error("You must be signed in first!");
  }

  const taken = await Firebase.usernameTaken(newUsername);
  if (taken) {
    throw new Error("Sorry, that username is taken.");
  }

  const lowerCurrentUsername = currentUsername.toLowerCase();
  const lowerNewUsername = newUsername.toLowerCase();
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const batch = db.batch();
  
  batch.delete(db.collection("uniqueUsers").doc(lowerCurrentUsername));
  batch.update(db.collection("users").doc(user.uid), {
    username: lowerNewUsername
  });
  batch.set(db.collection("uniqueUsers").doc(lowerNewUsername), {
    username: lowerNewUsername,
    uid: user.uid
  });

  await batch.commit();

  return lowerNewUsername;
}
```

```
// elsewhere in your code
changeUsername("olduser", "newuser")
  .then(
    (username) => {
      alert("Your username was successfully changed to @" + username + "!");
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
      alert("We couldn't update your username!");
    }
  );
```

Note: If you are using all of the above recommendations (like the security rules), one of the expected ways `batch.commit()` will fail is if someone takes the username before the current user. If you get a permissions error, assume that someone took the username before you.

Comment: Wow that is a very detailed explanation and you gave me some very nice tips! I can't express how much I appreciate you taking the time to help me and catch some future errors! Thank you again, and have a great day!

Comment: Hey, would you be able to send me your contact information, I would like to pitch you a startup idea that I would like you have you as a partner for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this check if your values are empty or not defined throw some error in try block  e.g.

```
cosnt user = Firebase.getCurrentUser();
const name = Firebase.usernameTaken(newUsername); 
// throwing error 
if(name == "") throw "is empty"; 
await db.collection('uniqueUsers').doc(currentUsername).delete();
```